# how to run a SKAction in the direction of a joystick's degree

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

i am creating a game and i am having trouble making my bullets spawn in the direction of my joystick. here is the method for my bullets

```
func spawnBullets(){

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png") 
    bullet.zPosition = -5
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x, hero.position.y)        
    bullet.xScale = 0.25
    bullet.yScale = 0.25
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
    bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet
    bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
    bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 1.0)     
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    self.addChild(bullet)
}
```

here is how i am calling the method in my

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, 
selector: Selector ("spawnBullets"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

and here is how i coded my touches moved function (i believe that is the method that i need to edit)

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: 
UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: 
        location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
        let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
        let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
        let length: CGFloat = joystickBase.frame.size.height / 2
        let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * length
        let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * length
        print(deg + 180)

        if (stickActive == true) {

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystickBase.frame, location)) {

            joystick.position = location

        }else{

joystick.position = CGPointMake(joystickBase.position.x - 
xDist, joystickBase.position.y + yDist)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only moving the bullets in a vertical direction:

`let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 1.0)`

Not sure if this is a twin stick game or not.

To get sprites to go based on the joystick, just do the following

```
let accel = 10 //accel is the # of pixels the sprite moves per frame, do not use moveTo, because moveTo will change the speeds of your sprite based on distance   
let action = SKAction.moveByX(joystick.x * accel,y:joystick.y * accel,duration:1)
```

This of course is based on the understanding that your joystick coordinates go from -1.0 to 1.0 on each axis, and that point up or right gets you a 1.0 result

I would not even do this approach though, SKActions are not a good choice for things that are not automated.  You should be updating the position of the sprite at some point in your update phase

```
sprite.position.x += joystick.x * accel
sprite.position.y += joystick.y * accel
```

Comment: @knightOfdragon could you give me an example of the code with your advice implemented? i tried using your method but i got a couple of errors

Comment: You cant just copy any paste,  and i am not sure what code you want me to give,  what i post goes right in the update statement,  however you get your  joystick values is dependent on you

Comment: @knightOfDragon which method do you call it in? the spawnBullet method? or the DidMoveToView? what do you mean by sprite.position.x ? are you talking about the bullet's position because i need the bullet to spawn first at the hero then move in the direction of the joystick And what do you recommend me using apposed to a SKAction if you would not take this approach?

Comment: @KnightOfDragon so i declare                                                                                                             let accel = 10 //accel is the # of pixels the sprite moves per frame, do not use moveTo, because moveTo will change the speeds of your sprite based on distance   
let action = SKAction.moveByX(joystick.x * accel,y:joystick.y * accel,duration:1) in my update method or                                              prite.position.x += joystick.x * accel  
sprite.position.y += joystick.y * accel                                          or both?

Comment: @KnightOfDragon how would i do sprite.position, if my bullet is not a sprite declared in the game I have a spawn bullets method. do you recommend me declaring it in my SKScene? and what joystick values are you talking about?

Comment: Find a tutoral on sprite kit

Comment: also, your bullets should be using skactions,  that is automated, but the player sprite should not

Comment: @KnightOfDragon are there any that you recommend?

Comment: @knightOfDragon your information was very vague and did not work. I regret voting up your answer

Comment: My answer is not vague, if you do not understand where your update function is, or how to position a sprite, then I recommend you stop what you are doing, pick up a few books, read a few tutorials, and try to understand how sprite kit works before you continue this process.

Comment: @knightOfdragon on this line                 let action = SKAction.moveByX(joystick.x * accel,y:joystick.y * accel,duration:1)
i get an error that says SK sprite node has no member X

Comment: Because you didnt read my answer. You dont just copy and paste my code

Comment: and what sprite are you referring to in the update phase? sprite.position.x += joystick.x * accel sprite.position.y += joystick.y * accel @KnightOfDragon

Comment: Sprite is your sprite that is on screen